# How do I define an argument in a method only if it isn't defined in __init__()?

Tags: python, oop, methods, initialization, arguments

For example, I want to create a class that can do different things with or without an initialized variable, but I want to keep it flexible, so that if the class is created without that argument, it can be added in with a method later. I have:

```
class Kickass(object):

    def __init__(self, website=None)
        if website:
            self.website = website

    def kick_butt(self):

        # Can do stuff even if website == None
        return stuff

    def web_scrape(self, site=None):

        if site:
            try:
                self.website == None
            except ValueError:
                print('Class instance already has a website!')
        # Do operations with method's argument

        if not site:
            if self.website == None:
                raise ValueError('Neither method nor instance have defined a website!')
            else:
            # Do operations with instance's variable
```

I'm still terrible at classes and handling exceptions. Thanks in advance for your input.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't throw an expection unless the behavior is actually *exceptional.* In your case, it seems like you want to check for a case, and have your behavior change based on that. So just check

```
if self.website is not None:
    DoThisThing
else:
    DoTheOtherThing
```

The reason your try/except doesn't work like you expect is that try/except doesn't work like if/else.

Instead try/except will first try to run the code in the try block. If the code runs fine, then it skips except and continues on. But if the code throws and `Exception` then it will run an except block that *catches that particular exception*.

Your try block looks like this:

```
try:
    self.website == None
```

Now, if self.website is None, then the code in the try block resolves to True. This isn't an exception, so the except block won't be executed. If self.website isn't none, then this block will resolve to False, which is also not an exception, so the except block won't run.

Now, if your try block looked like this:

```
try:
    len(self.website)
```

the code inside of try would throw `TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()`

so if you followed that with

```
except TypeError:
    print("This will run now")
```

your except block would execute.

You use try/except to deal with exceptions that your code throws (often when the runtime data is different that what was expected). Use if/else specify contingencies in normal operating cases.

Comment: That makes sense. I probably just need to rethink the logic of the whole thing.